# Evaluating an integral using Cauchy Integral Formula and a further application

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question:**

$i)$ Evaluate $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{e^{2z}}{z}dz$$

Where $\gamma=${$z\in \Bbb{C}: \lvert z\rvert$=1}

$ii)$ Hence find $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}{e^{2\cos(t)}}.\cos(2\sin(t) dt$$

**My attempt:**

$i)$ I believe the answer to this is $2\pi i$ by Cauchy's Integral Formula as $z=0$ is the only singularity in $\gamma$

$ii)$ This is where I am running into difficulty as I cannot see how the two integrals relate to each other.
$$\cos(2\sin(t)=\frac{e^{2\sin(t)i}+e^{-2\sin(t)i}}{2}$$

Which wouldn't have suggest that this doesn't have any singularities therefore by Cauchy Goursat the integral is equal to 0. I'm almost sure this is incorrect as I have not made any use of the previous question.

Comment: Where am I missing the $i\sin(t)$?

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused at which part you are talking about. Would you be able to elaborate please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Cauchy's formula we have
$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{e^{2z}}{z}dz = 2 \pi i. $$
But now recall the original definition of the complex integral. We let $\gamma(t) = e^{it}$. Then 
$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{e^{2z}}{z}dz = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{e^{2e^{it}}}{e^{it}}ie^{it} dt = i\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{2\cos(t)+2i\sin(t)} dt =i\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{2\cos(t)}\cos(2\sin(t))dt - \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{2\cos(t)}\sin(2\sin(t)) dt= 2\pi i. $$
We conclude $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{2\cos(t)}\cos(2\sin(t))dt=2 \pi,$$
by equating imaginary parts.

Comment: Thank you for your help! However shouldn't it be $-2\pi$

Comment: Sorry I understand now! However where does the second integral go?

Comment: We can conclude the second integral is zero! This is because if $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, $a+bi = c+di$ if and only if $a=b$ and $c=d$.

Comment: I see! Thank you for your help